# There is consistency among whole indian philosophical schools?

Tags: metaphysics, consciousness, history

i try to prove this by Buddha's &sankara's concept of Consciousness".bcoz both are represent two different tradition (Samanic & Vedic).
2.  Both stressed the impermanence of worldly life.
3. buddha emphasis by knowing this impermanence world  one can attain moska
Sankara suggests by realising the Brahman one can know the world is not eternal.
why Consciousness
i. consciousness is the study what is human. it is impossible to conceive  a human without consciousness. even in coma v say that the person is without consciousness.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: If the question is whether there was consistency the answer depends on what "consistency" means. Shankara is particularly known for polemically structured commentary, where criticisms of other Indian schools lead up to elaborating his own position. There was a deep influence of Mahayana Buddhism on Advaita, but, as Shankara himself stressed, according to Advaita soul exists and is self-evident while according to Buddhism it is self-evident that there is no soul, approaches are different. See [Buddhist influences on Advaita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_influences_on_Advaita_Vedanta).

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Read "The Advaita Tradition in Indian Philosophy" or "A Critical Survey of Indian Philosophy" both by Chandradhar Sharma. He gives a detailed description of the development and history of these ideas as well as the historical figures and thoughts that developed. More details than most people are aware. There is no difference philosophically between Mahayana Buddhism and Advaita Vedanta. Buddha was a 'crypto-Advaitain'. "Both are stages in the development of the same Upanisadic thought."

Comment: There are indefinitely many schools of Indian philosophy. You mention two. If you are asking about the reconciliation between these two schools - their agreement in assumptions, deductions, basic concepts, &c. - it would be better to rephrase the question to focus on them.